# How to protect phpmyadmin with fail2ban?

Tags: phpmyadmin, fail2ban

I  would  like  to  protect  PhPmyadmin  login against  bruteforce  attacks with  fail2ban
How can  I  enable log failed  logins  in phpmyadmin  and  what  filter  should  I  use  in fail2ban  for  phpmyadmin could  somebody  writes  the  steps  what  I  should  do  my  phpmyadmin  running port 9000

I  have  tried  to  add  these  lines  to  /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    

    
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{userID}n %        {userStatus}n" pma_combined

    
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log pma_combined
   </VirtualHost>
```

And  then
make  a  filter in
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
 [Definition]
 denied = mysql-denied|allow-denied|root-denied|empty-denied
 failregex = ^<HOST> -.*(?:%(denied)s)$
 ignoreregex =
```

Finally  add  jail  in   /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
 [phpmyadmin]
 enabled = true
 port = http,https
 filter = phpmyadmin
 logpath = /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log
```